# How does adding a mass change fluid flow rate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I have this exercise:

[image]

I haven't had any trouble solving the first two parts, but regarding the third one, I was wondering if my reasoning is correct. I would say that for the first case in which the object floats, then $h_1$ would not change, but the pressure at A would. Thus, I calculated this new pressure knowing the mass and radius of the tank, and got the new speed at D. However, if the object sinks, the Pressure at A would not change but $h_1$ would.

Can I say anything else about this? Is it correct?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't $h_1$ change in the first scenario?

Comment: Well, since the object is floating, I just thought that it did not affect the water level and thus $h_1$ would remain unchanged. Is this incorrect? @JMac

Comment: [Archimedes' Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) describes how you should expect the water level to change.

Comment: @JMac Okay, and in the case where there is floating, there would be no watwr displacement correct?

Comment: I suggest you re-read the link or look up some examples on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider how the mass of the weight will displace the fluid. How will that effect the level of the fluid? Will there be a difference in the level if 10kg floated on the surface or displaced fluid under the liquid level?

Comment: Well... I think that if it floats on the surface, it will not change the level of what is underneath; if it sinks, then obviously it will... but I am not whether I have the right idea @Gwydionforge

Comment: What happens to the level of the bath when you get in? Or go all the way under?

Comment: It changes depending on how much I submerge myself, but I wouldn't expect it to change if I was floating... @Gwydionforge

Comment: @Bee So when you float, there used to be water where you were floating.  If the water doesn't rise, where does the water you displace go?

Comment: Put a ping pong ball in a cup of water, watch the water as you push the ball down. You still displace water when you float. Think of a large ship, they categorize them by displacement; a 200k ton displacement tug will displace 200k ton of water.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you so much for the insight? Then, the problem cannot be solved right? Since we do not have any idea of the volume of the object or its density, we cannot calculate the volume of watwr it displaces. @Gwydionforge

Comment: It can be solved if you determine the volume of that exact weight of displaced water and add it to the head pressure

Comment: @Bee The volume doesn't matter; because it must displace it's own _mass_ of water.  You know the volume of your container and the density of _water_, so you can determine how much that displaced mass in water will raise the height.

Comment: But, I thought that Archimede's principle talks about how the displaced volume of water will be the same as that of the submerged part of the solid. Here, we just have the mass of the solid; not its density nor its volume. Is it okay then, to say that a 10 kg object will displace 10 kg of water (i.e. 10 L of water)? @JMac

Comment: @Bee It does both.  The crux of Archimedes principle is that the weight of displaced volume of water will be _equal to_ the weight of the object floating.  The volume displaced will also be the volume submerged.  When the objects becomes more dense, it submerges fully and still hasn't displaced enough water to support it, so it sinks and displaces only it's volume, not it's weight.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you so much!! In my class, we went over all fluid dynamics in two hours so it was impossible to get a full grasp of all the theorems. Thank you so much for the insight @JMac